# Eclipse Luna displaying regular scrollbars instead of overlay scrollbars - how to change?

Tags: unity, gui, eclipse, gtk, overlay-scrollbars

I've recently switched to using the new Eclipse Luna, but for some reason it stopped displaying the overlay scrollbars, and now shows the regular ones that are in e.g. Firefox. Kepler had them.

Since Eclipse UI is cluttered already, I would like to turn them back on, how can that be done?

Comment: Downvoted by mistake. Can a mod please change it to an upvote?

Comment: I will never forgive you for this /s Anyway I think you can change it now, since I've edited it a bit.

Comment: There you go ;)

Comment: This would be dependet on graphics driver and about whether you installed then gnome completely or whether you prefer a) vesa - b) xorg-stuff ... ?! - this is what was not missing in 12.10 and not missing in 12.04.(??) LTS

Comment: @dschinn1001 Could you elaborate? How would this depend on my driver? Overlay scrollbars work in other applications - and also in Eclipse Kepler (same application, different release). And what additional packages should I install if that's what you're saying?

Comment: Go in Windows>Preferences>Appearance. What theme is displeyed?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Ubuntu **12.04** or **14.04**, you need to start Eclipse with an env var to force overlay scrollbars:

```
env LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=1 eclipse
```

As I'm using a downloaded Eclipse (and not the one provided by apt), I've created a `Eclipse.desktop` file (under `~/.local/share/applications/`) with the following content (remember to replace `<path_to_eclipse_folder>` by your path to Eclipse:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Eclipse
Comment=Integrated IDE
Icon=eclipse.png
Exec=env LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=1 /<path_to_eclipse_folder>/eclipse
Categories=Application;Development;Java;PHP;IDE;
Type=Application
Terminal=false
```

Comment: Does no longer work for me in **eclipse neon**

Comment: @MrSmith42 Which Ubuntu version? My answer was valid until 14.04 and for Luna. On Xenial (16.04) I know the Canonical overlay scrollbar was replaced by the Gnome one and that newest Eclipse are using GTK3 (which has some issues with Ubuntu).

Comment: I use ubuntu 16.04 now with eclipse neon. unfortunately I found no solution for this constellation yet.

Answer (score 0):

This works on Eclipse Neon

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop
```

Then copy and paste this, make sure to point to your ***eclipse*** in ***/opt/***

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Eclipse 4
Type=Application
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 SWT_GTK3=0 /opt/eclipse/eclipse
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
Comment=Integrated Development Environment
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Development;IDE;
Name[en]=Eclipse NEON
```